# PostBack Not firing for Asp Dot Net target Framework 4.7

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I have two applications
Application 1 : Desktop Console Application
Application 2 : ASP Dot Net Web Application

I submit a form application 1, so that there should be a postback event fired up. It does but as soon as I enforce HttpRuntime dot net version 4.7 in web.config of a Application2(Web App). The postBack Stops firing.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7" maxRequestLength="2097151"/>
```

Application 1's Code :

```
    private static string m_autoLoginFormContents = null;

    static void Main()
    {
        //DECLARE INTERNET EXPLORER OBJECT
        SHDocVw.InternetExplorer m_autologinIEWindow = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();

        //ASSOCIATE HANDLER TO DOCUMENT COMPLETE EVENT
        m_autologinIEWindow.DocumentComplete += URLAutologinDocumentCompleteEventHandler;

        //NAVIGATE THE URL
        m_autologinIEWindow.Navigate("about:blank");
        m_autologinIEWindow.AddressBar = true;
        m_autologinIEWindow.Visible = true;
        System.Console.Read();

    }

    //HANDLER DEFINITION
    public static void URLAutologinDocumentCompleteEventHandler(object senderObject, ref object objectTwo /* not sure what this argument is for */)
    {
        System.Console.Write("I am here in Document Complete");

        m_autoLoginFormContents = "<form runat = \"server\" name = \"AutoLoginForm\" action = \"http://localhost:12810/ei/Login.aspx\" method = POST><input type = hidden name = \"tbUsername\" value = \"ECTNAMbarora\"><input type = hidden name = \"tbPassword\" value = \"Barora1#1\"><input type = hidden name = \"__VIEWSTATE\" value = \"/wEPDwUKMTUxNzY2NTkwNQ9kFgICAw9kFgICAQ9kFgJmD2QWAgIBD2QWAgIBDw8WAh4HVmlzaWJsZWhkZGTOFG2synRTKe8uLtoYBL1c8DCnow==\"><input type = hidden name = \"__EVENTARGUMENT\" value = \"\"><input type = hidden name = \"__EVENTTARGET\" value = \"\"><input type = hidden name = \"__EVENTVALIDATION\" value = \"/wEWBQKInY2gBALStq24BwK3jsrkBAKC3IeGDAKVyIalD9DFZ+2yZSlAiApijC71lY9wtsqo\"><input type = hidden name = \"utcOffset\" value = \"8\"><input type = hidden name = \"btnLogin\" value = \"Login\">";
        SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = senderObject as SHDocVw.InternetExplorer;
        mshtml.HTMLDocument document = IE.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;

        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("afterBegin", m_autoLoginFormContents);
        mshtml.IHTMLFormElement formElement = document.forms.item("AutoLoginForm") as mshtml.IHTMLFormElement;
        formElement.submit();

        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Application 2 :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (IsPostBack){
            //System.Console.Read();
            System.Console.Write("Bhavya has reached postback");
        }
    }
```

If I enforce it never goes in the IsPostBack Block.

**Note :
My original problem was an event not firing, I wrote a short code to show the problem. 

Not sure if that's the problem,
 
I found a page, which says Event Handling is broken and tells a way around, but I don't know how to do that, what would be the HttpModule name, etc as I am super new to Dot Net Programming!**

The Page which tells the work around : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770154

**EDIT**

I tried adding :

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7" maxRequestLength="2097151" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

And
 `validateRequest="false"` for  to turn off request validation, but still got the problem

Comment: What is the purpose of changing the httpruntime in config file to 4.7?Why you did that? Do you want to change the .NET framework for your application?

Comment: Hmmm... you're injecting a HTML form into a page, that contains values which should be generated by the server (__VIEWSTATE, __EVENTARGUMENT). Then trying submit said form to cause the server to log you in. I'm not surprised that this is not working for you, and you're probably having request validation errors. The .NET framework version is likely a red herring. I think you need to take a few steps back and explain what it is you're trying to achieve, because your current approach looks like you're out of your depth, and continuing this path may only cause you more issues.

Comment: @Adrian I am trying to log into one application using another application that would already be having the username and password stored. To make it easy for stack overflow, I didn't read the values but inserted in the form as it would become arduous to understand the problem.

This is a part of a big application, so modifying ways would be difficult. It always used to work, what is with the 4.7 that it stopped working.

Comment: @Adrian <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7" maxRequestLength="2097151" **requestValidationMode="2.0"/> And validateRequest="false"** for <pages /> to turn off request validation, but still got the problem .

Comment: Cool, in my opinion, showing that you're finding the login form on the page and then giving a sample form is less arduous. But anyway, does logging in from the Browser work when changing framework? Have you  tried capturing the request and response using Telerik's fiddler to make sure that there is no differences when the framework is changed? Best capture a login attempt from you client app and browser too to compare.

Comment: What's the .NET framework version being used before you target 4.7 specifically?